# How to add opamp noise density in LTspice

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise, ltspice

I have this circuit in LTSpice using the universalOpamp2:

[image]

The simulation gives me 30 nV/sqrt(Hz). If the opamp noise density is specified in the datasheet as 5 nV/sqrt(Hz), I understand I have to add 4 x 5 nV/sqrt(Hz) = 20 nV/sqrt(Hz) to my 30 nV/sqrt(Hz) to get my overall noise of 50 nV/sqrt(Hz). However, how do I do confirm this in LTSpice? I would like the 5 nV/sqrt(Hz) opamp noise density be part of the simulation.

Comment: you cant add 30 and 20 here, because the two sources are uncorrelated and add orthogonally, i.e. sqrt(30² + 20²) = 36. there will be also considerable noise due to R4 itself. more than from the opamp. ltspice correctly considers opamp noise, but unfortunately cannot display it as component-wise contribution like for e.g. resistors

Comment: OK, thanks for the correction. Still though, isn't it possible to add a parameter to have the 5 nV/sqrt(Hz) included in the simulation?

Comment: It is always included if you specified this value as the corresponding property in the UniversalOpamp model. try changing the value to 0 and you will find that vout noise decreases. but it will decrease by much less than 4x5nV/rtHz due to noises being uncorrelated as explained before.

Comment: Oh, it's the parameter En. Got it.

Comment: You have 3 uncorrelated noise source groups to consider; R1||R2, R3 & R4, and the opamp. The gain = Vout/Vin is 2 since R1 & R2 form a voltage divider. This affects equivalent noise input (\$ e_n \$). You also need to consider input current noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The noise figures are added via the parameters En, Enk, In, Ink of universalOpamp2.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a voltage noise source and/or current noise source for use with LTspice you can download such noise sources on my GitHub page https://github.com/yildi1337/LTspiceNoiseSources.

Below you can find screenshots of two examples:

[image: Example with voltage noise source]
[image: Example with current noise source]

Comment: While the UniversalOpamp has native support for 1/f noise this is a cool thing to simulate current noise in resistors!

Comment: That's a nice setup you have on github. +1.